# Not being able to reach MySQL data

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin, appserver

I've been using AppServ which includes MySQL, PHP, Apache24 and phpMyAdmin features.

One day, I accidentally uninstalled my AppServ service from my computer and I had to install it yet again. Everything was OK until I saw my database is not working correctly as it used to be.

I'm somehow not able to reach my data so are the websites I made before the accident happened. When I go to my phpMyAdmin, I can clearly see the structures I made but not their content which is the issue. In fact, they're all standing there when I see them in the directory.

[image: Here you see it says the data doesn't exist but it actually does]

[image: This is a view from the directory and it all seems good I suppose]

Thanks in advance.

**NOTE:** The AppServ uninstalling process does not remove your own data.

Comment: please create an archive and upload somewhere and put in Your question. let us try to recover and provide sql dump. or add me in skype: `anarjafarov`  I'll help You

Comment: What you mean by "archive"?

Comment: I mean put that files somewhere, I'll download and try to fix it.

Comment: You mean data files?

Comment: I added you in Skype. Please check it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To recover database from `.frm` and contents from `.ibd` You have to do following:

1)  create temporary database to avoid suddenly working with other databases.

```
CREATE DATABASE soru_sor_recover;
```

2) generate `CREATE TABLE` dumps from `.frm` files (You'll need to install `mysql-utilities` [from here](https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/utilities/));

```
mysqlfrm –diagnostic answers.frm >> create_table.txt
mysqlfrm –diagnostic categories.frm >> create_table.txt
mysqlfrm –diagnostic inbox.frm >> create_table.txt
mysqlfrm –diagnostic questions.frm >> create_table.txt
mysqlfrm –diagnostic users.frm >> create_table.txt
```

3) import `create_table.txt` using some gui or just by terminal:

```
mysql -u root -p soru_sor_recover < create_table.txx
```

4) now we have tables but they are empty. so we have to replace `.ibd` file of empty tables with ibd files of recovery. so we need to discard tablespace:

```
ALTER TABLE answers DISCARD TABLESPACE; 
ALTER TABLE categories DISCARD TABLESPACE; 
ALTER TABLE inbox DISCARD TABLESPACE; 
ALTER TABLE questions DISCARD TABLESPACE; 
ALTER TABLE users DISCARD TABLESPACE;
```

5) replace `.ibd` files in data folder and define user and group for that files:

```
cp *.ibd /var/lib/mysql/soru_sor_recover
chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql/soru_sor_recover/*.ibd
```

6) restart mysql:

```
/etc/init.d/mysql restart
```

7) enable table spaces, go to mysql console:

```
ALTER TABLE answers IMPORT TABLESPACE; 
ALTER TABLE categories IMPORT TABLESPACE; 
ALTER TABLE inbox IMPORT TABLESPACE; 
ALTER TABLE questions IMPORT TABLESPACE; 
ALTER TABLE users IMPORT TABLESPACE;
```

original source of documenatation [is here](https://www.voxteneo.com/restoring-tables-mysql-database-frm-ibd-files-available/)

Comment: You're amazing in every word. Thank you so much for all this willing of yours!